# partial data populated into table from xml in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, html

I am using AJAX call to load and parse xml. I already have a table created and inside for each loop I am inserting data into table. Problem is it is inserting only about 3000 rows  while xml has data for 16000 rows. I have created local database (client side) in HTML5.

Any answers or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: please post the code you have so far

Comment: It could be related to a storage limitations... share your code, it wight help to highlight the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hm. My only guesses are either of these things:

1. the XML file is broken somewhere; if you open it in a browser, does it render correctly?
2. you hit the max size for [HTML 5's local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/max-size-of-localstorage-values)